# how to delete a line in a text file in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

my file is text.txt with content

```
resources :albums, except: [:new, :edit, :destroy] 
resources :conversation_replies, except: [:new, :edit, :destroy] 
resources :authors, except: [:new, :edit, :destroy] 
.........
```

Now, I want to delete a line in this file. example, I want delete line with content with the characters such as: conversation_replies

Please help me. thank you very much

Comment: in ruby exactly, or enough bash?

Comment: You can defiantly find your answer here:

[First][1] 


[Second][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16638667/how-do-i-remove-lines-of-data-in-the-middle-of-a-text-file-with-ruby
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17854731/deleting-a-line-in-a-text-file

Comment: @jvperrin Are you aware it's the same guy? He is trying to programatically delete entries in his `routes.rb` file. He was told it's just a text file, so now we have this... Check out his example text.

Answer (score 0):

```
system("cat youfile | grep -v conversation_replies > yourfile.bak)
system("mv youfile.bak yourfile")
```

Answer (score 0):

ruby `code` in txt file?

Pretty much hard-coding..

1. `Read` and store content into a variable using `File.read(*path*)`
2. `Split` contents based on `/n` (new line)
3. Loop each line and `split` then `match` the content
4. On `true` push empty space, join file with `\n`
5. `Save` and `close` the file.